# Raspberry Pi 3 with Microstack GPS (latest GPS data)

Tags: python-3

I implemented the following code:

```
gps = microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps.L80GPS()
while True:
    data = gps.get_gprmc()
    print(data.keys(), data.values())
    time.sleep(1)
```

After some time it starts to output data with a time delay which increases with time. Here I am talking about 10 min delay in a 30-min run. It seems that the problem is coming from the serial port where all the data are buffered and I am getting not the latest data but whatever came to the port first.
Has anyone had similar issue and what is the best solution to overcome this problem?

Comment: Do you mean that after 30 minutes, it takes 10 minutes to print the next line? Or do you mean that the first line has a timestamp T, and the line which appears after 30 minutes has a timestamp T+20min?

Comment: Not Pi specific.  Personally I would read the device more often.

Comment: I save data to the file with two timestamps: one from RPi T_rpi and one provided from GPS T_gps. At the beggining of the file T_rpi = T_gps, and after 30 min the last line shows T_gps = T_rpi - 10 min